Night Light from terminal with Ubuntu 23 and 24, gsettings no longer updating the entry in DCONF
Hi I used to use this command to toggle night light from the terminal but it no longer seems to update the setting but going to the dconf editor and toggling the setting works fine
Switch on
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled true

Toggle
bash -c "if [[ $(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled) == "true" ]]; then gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled false; else gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled true; fi"

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction...

I cannot test in Ubuntu because I do not have it for the moment on hardware, but your commands appear correct, and immediately work for me on Fedora on a Dell XPS with Intel graphics card. When executing the command with dconf-editor open, is the value updated there?

@vanadium no the value is not updated in dconf at all and changing the value with dconf editor works as expected. Even getting the value from DCONF using gsettings get doesn't show the current value.

It will be good to add that information into your post. Not sure what is going on on your system: I tested in a VM and the command does update the value in dconf-editor.
